# Fiber product of irreducible curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Consider a collection $Y_1,\ldots,Y_n$ of absolutely irreducible curves define over a field $\mathbb{K}$ each equipped with a map to another curve $Z$. Is $X=Y_1\times_Z\ldots\times_Z Y_n$ absolutely irreducible?

Comment: What is the definition of _absolutely irreducible curve_?

Comment: @Armandoj18eos It means irreducible over an algebraic closure. So stronger than irreducible. But would be happy to know the answer for just irreducible.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't konw the definition of "irreducible set over another set": can you explain me?

Comment: @Armandoj18eos That is just additional information that is not necessary for the problem. The fact that they are "over" $Z$ just means that each of the curves comes equipped with a map to $Z$. You can ignore that, I just want to know if the fiber product of (absolutely) irreducible curves is (absolutely) irreducible. Ill edit the wording of the problem to make it more clear.

Comment: @Armandoj18eos I guess the maps to $Z$ are not entirely irrelevant since you need them to define the fiber product.

Answer (score 0):

By definition of fibre product of schemes: there exists a canonical morphism $X\to Z$, that is $X$ is a scheme *over* $Z$; however $X$ is not irreducible in general.

**Example.** Let $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{Q}$, $Z=\mathrm{Spec}\mathbb{Q}[z],\,Y_1=Y_2=\mathrm{Spec}\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})[x]$ and the morphisms of schemes of $Y$'s over $Z$ are induced by the canonical inclusion $\mathbb{Q}[x]\hookrightarrow\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})[x]$. One has
\begin{gather}
\dim_{Krull}Y_1=\dim_{Krull}Y_2=\dim_{Krull}Z=1,\\
Y_1,\,Y_2\,\text{and}\,Z\,\text{are irreducible (curves) over}\,\mathbb{Q},\\
X=\mathrm{Spec}\left(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})[x]\otimes_{\mathbb{Q}[z]}\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})[y]\right)\cong\mathrm{Spec}\left(\mathbb{Q}[x,t]_{\displaystyle/(t^2-2)}\otimes_{\mathbb{Q}[z]}\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})[y]\right)\cong\\
\cong\mathrm{Spec}\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})[x,t]_{\displaystyle/(t^2-2)}\cong\mathrm{Spec}\left(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})[x]\times\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})[y]\right)=\\
=\mathrm{Spec}\left(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})[x]\right)\coprod\mathrm{Spec}\left(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})[y]\right)
\end{gather}
that is $X$ is the union of two (irreducible) curves over $\mathbb{Q}$. $(Q.E.D\,\Box)$

Comment: $X$ should be two copies of $A^1_{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})}$

Comment: Why? What is my mistake?

Comment: In this step $\mathrm{Spec}\left(\mathbb{Q}[x,t]_{\displaystyle/(t^2-2)}\otimes_{\mathbb{Q}[z]}\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})[y]\right)\cong\mathrm{Spec}\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})[x,y,t]_{\displaystyle/(t^2-2)}$, $x$ should be deleted on RHS.